# Reshaping batch variable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, transpose

In Tensorflow, I would like to reshape a batch variable **A** of form 
`[100, 32, 32]` into **B** of form `[10, 10, 32, 32]`. But naively using reshape loses the order information.

For example, `A[10,:,:]` is not the same as `B[1,0,:,:]` where the 1 denotes the next line of the mini-batch of 10s.

I want the orders of `32*32` unchanged since its an image, while I want to reshape 100 of these images in the following fashion:

1 -> 2 -> ... -> 10

11 -> 12 -> ... ->  20

...
...

91 -> 92 -> ... -> 100

How can I do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.reshape` do what you want, if I right understood what you want. For example:

```
data = np.array(range(100*32*32)).reshape((100,32,32))
A = tf.constant(data)
B = tf.reshape(A, [10, 10, 32, 32])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("A")
    print(sess.run(A)[10, :, :])
    print()
    print("B")
    print(sess.run(B)[1, 0, :, :])
```

output:

```
A
 [[10240 10241 10242 ..., 10269 10270 10271]
  [10272 10273 10274 ..., 10301 10302 10303]
  [10304 10305 10306 ..., 10333 10334 10335]
  ...,
  [11168 11169 11170 ..., 11197 11198 11199]
  [11200 11201 11202 ..., 11229 11230 11231]
  [11232 11233 11234 ..., 11261 11262 11263]]

B
 [[10240 10241 10242 ..., 10269 10270 10271]
  [10272 10273 10274 ..., 10301 10302 10303]
  [10304 10305 10306 ..., 10333 10334 10335]
  ...,
  [11168 11169 11170 ..., 11197 11198 11199]
  [11200 11201 11202 ..., 11229 11230 11231]
  [11232 11233 11234 ..., 11261 11262 11263]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.unstack` and then `tf.stack`.

For example:

```py
A = tf.random_uniform([100, 32, 32])
temp = tf.unstack(t)
B = tf.stack([temp[pos:pos+10] for pos in range(0, len(temp), 10)]
```

or a little more transparent and flexible:

```py
def chunker(seq, size):
    return [seq[pos:pos+size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size)]

B = tf.stack(chunker(temp,10))
```